# JS - Moving keys from object to another object

Tags: javascript

I have list of books:

```
let myBooks = [{"id":8,"name":"Don Quijote","author":"Cervantes"},{"id":9,"name":"Romeo and Juliet","author":"Shakespeare"},{"id":10,"name":"Hamlet","author":"Shakespeare"},{"id":11,"name":"Othello","author":"Shakespeare"},{"id":"12","nazev":"Antigona","autor":"Sofokles"}]
```

I need to find out how to create new object with authors and how many times are they in `myBooks` like this:

```
let authorsInMyBooks = [{"Cervantes":1},{"Shakespeare":3},{"Sofokles":1}]
```

I tried this:

```
for (i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {
            if (myBooks[i].author in authorsInMyBooks) {
                authorsInMyBooks[myBooks[i].author] += 1;
            } else {
                authorsInMyBooks[myBooks[i].author] = 1;
            }
        }
```

But output was:

```
[{"Cervantes":5, "Shakespeare":9, "Sofokles":1}]
```

I am calling function with for loop every time, when I add new book to `myBooks`

Comment: The script shown works as expected/requested: https://jsfiddle.net/txw1rp29/ (if you fix the typo then it will also show `Sofokles` instead of `undefined`)

Comment: @Andreas I get `{ Cervantes: 1, Shakespeare: 3, undefined: 1 }` in firefox. - Ah you have a minor spelling mistake in the fiddle.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Because there's a typo in OPs example (`"autor":"Sofokles"`). But the numbers are as requestes (1, 3, 1).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use an empty object as initial value of `authorsInMyBooks` and then use `map()` to get an array.

```js
let myBooks = [{"id":8,"name":"Don Quijote","author":"Cervantes"},{"id":9,"name":"Romeo and Juliet","author":"Shakespeare"},{"id":10,"name":"Hamlet","author":"Shakespeare"},{"id":11,"name":"Othello","author":"Shakespeare"},{"id":"12","nazev":"Antigona","autor":"Sofokles"}]

let authorsInMyBooks = {}
for (let i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {
   if (authorsInMyBooks[myBooks[i].author]) {
      authorsInMyBooks[myBooks[i].author] += 1;
   } else {
      authorsInMyBooks[myBooks[i].author] = 1;
   }
}

authorsInMyBooks = Object.entries(authorsInMyBooks).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}));

console.log(authorsInMyBooks)
```

You can use `reduce()`

```js
let myBooks = [{"id":8,"name":"Don Quijote","author":"Cervantes"},{"id":9,"name":"Romeo and Juliet","author":"Shakespeare"},{"id":10,"name":"Hamlet","author":"Shakespeare"},{"id":11,"name":"Othello","author":"Shakespeare"},{"id":"12","nazev":"Antigona","autor":"Sofokles"}]

const res = myBooks.reduce((ac, {author}) => {
  ac[author] = (ac[author] || 0) + 1
  return ac;
}, {})

const authorsInMyBooks = Object.entries(res).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}));

console.log(authorsInMyBooks)
```

Comment: The script works, and this wouldn't explain the "strange" numbers OP claims to get es output.

Comment: @Andreas it does solve the issue of all authors and the numbers being added to one object inside the array.

Comment: Because I have tested it in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/txw1rp29/) which is a copy&paste of OPs script o.O

Comment: @Andreas Your snippet contains `let authorsInMyBooks = {};` which is no where inside the OP's code. I thought OP is using something other than empty object as its initial value.

Comment: `[{"Cervantes":5, "Shakespeare":9, "Sofokles":1}]`... The array doesn't add anything to the question/answer, hence I didn't add it...

Comment: @Andreas Can't say anything until OP gives some more details...

Comment: @machalik As does your own script... o.O

Comment: @MaheerAli after adding ```let authorsInMyBooks = {}``` works fine

Comment: @machalik If this part was missing completely then where is the shown "output" coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could make use of `Array.reduce` ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)), something like:

```js
const myBooks = [
  {"id":8,"name":"Don Quijote","author":"Cervantes"},
  {"id":9,"name":"Romeo and Juliet","author":"Shakespeare"},
  {"id":10,"name":"Hamlet","author":"Shakespeare"},
  {"id":11,"name":"Othello","author":"Shakespeare"},
  {"id":"12","nazev":"Antigona","author":"Sofokles"} ];

const authorFreqs = Object.entries(
  myBooks
    .reduce( (accumulator, value) => 
      ( {...accumulator, [value.author]: accumulator[value.author] 
             ? accumulator[value.author] + 1 
             : 1} ),
      {}) )
    .map( ([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }) );

console.log(authorFreqs);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```